# Why is it showing "Error: Cannot open file" even though I created the text.txt and it's in my Desktop?

Tags: c

I just started learning C. This program's purpose is to read from a file, scan for uppercase letters and write those uppercase letters to a second file. I don't understand why it is showing up "Error: Cannot open file" when text.txt file exists on my desktop. I use Visual Studio, so could it be because it's not placed in source files?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp1, * fp2;
    char ch[1];

    fp1 = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError: Cannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fp2 = fopen("caps.txt", "w");

    while (ch != '\0')
    {
        fscanf(fp1, "%c", &ch);

        if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
        {
            putc(ch, fp2);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't debug the program when I can't access the text.txt file. Please help!

Comment: Hint: call fopen with the full path to the file.

Comment: It's because you're not telling `fopen` where the file is located, you're just providing a filename. Your application is not on your desktop, so why would your code just assume that it would find the file in that folder? It's like addressing a letter to *123 Main Street* without providing the name of the city and state - how would you expect that letter to get delivered where you want?

Answer (score 0):

With the case of using the visual studio, to open the given file by your way of writing it, you have to put it inside the folder which stores your .c and .h files. Overwise, you have to use relative or even full path.